# Cant access login to website from another network

Tags: web-services, web

My friend bought a new website and he asked me to maintain it since he does not know much about programming. I agreed but the problem is that I cannot access the login/cpanel into the website from my network, but When I work at his place I am able to login.
He gave me the password and everything to log in but it appears to me that the login can only be accessed from his network. How do I change it?

Comment: Could it be this? https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/restrict-whm-access-by-ip.119773/

Answer (score 0):

That depends highly on the hosting provider. I know from personal experience that BlueHost does this. You have to register your IP with them. It's for the best, that way there's an extra level of security. Poke around the cPanel for options. It's hard to tell you without more info, which I would advise not giving because of security. If you're with BlueHost, then let me know And I'll show you.